# mapping user-level threads to kernal

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

Is it possible to map **1** user-level thread to **many** kernel level threads or eg: 2 user-level threads to 3 or more kernel level and if the answer is yes. how does that change the performance in a positive way

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a user-level thread. That is the total BS creation of crappy textbooks on operating systems. If you have such a book, use it for cat box liner.

Threads are either implemented by the operating system (what bad textbook call "kernel threads") or they are simulated by run time libraries (user threads)——in which case they should not even be part of an operating system course except for historical context.

The kernel/user thread distinction is utterly confusing. Sometimes it is made even more confusing by bad textbooks talking about 1 to 1 and many to one and many to many models.

What you are describing could never happen outside the realm of textbooks. You either use real threads (kernel) or you use simulated threads (user) when real threads are not available. The latter is rarely the case these days as nearly every operating system you'd encounter has support for real threads.

It is unfortunate that operating system textbooks take such a simple concept and make it confusing.

Comment: almost all text books used to teach OS use this concept (eg: Operating Systems Internals and Design Principles, Operating System Concepts)

Comment: So there is no such thing as mapping 5 "user-level" to 3 "kernel-level" even if the system cant provide 5. Meaning you would either implement with  "user-level" or "kernel-level" so doing it with "user-level" does it increase the process time in the CPU? or it doesn't effect that at all (since kernel cant make a difference) which means no throughput increase

Comment: Most operating systems books suck. In the real word you use real threads (kernel) if you can. If you can't, you revert to simulated threads (user). To put in a student's mind that you could map 5 "user" threads to 3 "kernel" threads (and you're not the first) demonstrates how bad these books are.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to map 1 user-level thread to many kernel level threads or eg: 2 user-level threads to 3 or more kernel level and if the answer is yes. how does that change the performance in a positive way

Anything is possible in theory. The problem is finding a reason to do it.

More specifically, the problem is finding a way that additional kernel threads assigned to a user thread can be beneficial (and aren't just wasting resources). There are only 2 plausible scenarios I can think of where this might be beneficial in theory.

The first plausible scenario I'll call "adjustable width SIMD", where a single instruction might operate on N pieces of data at a time when there's only one kernel thread assigned, and where an instruction (running on M kernel threads on M CPUs) operates on N*M pieces of data at a time when there are M kernel threads assigned.

The second plausible scenario is redundancy. For example, if you assign 3 kernel threads to a user thread and compare the actions (e.g. stores to memory) of each kernel thread; then you'd be able to detect (and be immune to) some hardware failures (e.g. if a CPU becomes faulty causing one kernel thread to behave differently to other kernel threads).

Note that both of these cases would require purpose designed hardware to meet the synchronization requirements; and neither of these things are possible/practical for conventional CPUs (that have no support for the synchronization requirements).

Comment: for the first scenario dont you need to split the work into multiple part (which is already what a process does when making thread) so you would be making mini threads from the threads themselves in order to be able to map it

Comment: @YounesBalah: Let's define "thread" as a "thread of execution with its own independent instruction pointer". For both scenarios, in user-space you'd have a single "thread of execution" (e.g. one instruction pointer that happens to be controlling what 2 or more processors do), and in kernel-space you wouldn't (each processor would have its own independent kernel thread).

Comment: Yes. Note that to assign 2 or more kernel threads to one user thread you have to have 2 or more kernel threads running at the same time, and the only way that can happen is if each kernel thread has a different CPU (otherwise you'd just have 2 or more kernel threads running at different times and can't assign them to the same user thread at the same time).